# Kendo React Upload could not open file dialog

Tags: reactjs, kendo-upload, kendo-react-ui

I have a web application which used several kendo-react component and the kendo react upload have an issue where it could not open the file dialog when I click on the select files button. Previously, it worked perfectly and now it does not open the file dialog at all.

I have tried to update my kendo react upload library version to 5.16.1 but still cannot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.